# jquery mobile save button click event not firing

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am working on jQuery mobile controls. I have a jqgrid in a master page and on click of selected row id I am redirecting to another page with the id. In that page I have drop down which is bound with json. And after binding I want to save data to database on click of a button.

The problem is that the button click event is not firing, however, when I run that particular aspx on its own the button click event does fire.

```
 <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="btnsave"  data-transition="fade" 
      data-theme="b" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right" runat="server" 
      onserverclick="btnsave_click" >Save</a>
```

Comment: you might want to prepare an example with http://jsfiddle.net ...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `data-ajax="false"` to your link.

For example

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-ajax="false" data-inline="true" id="btnsave"
         data-transition="fade" data-theme="b"  data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right" 
         runat="server" onserverclick="btnsave_click" >Save</a>
```

Now for the explanation, by [default](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html) when you link to a page in jQuery Mobile, JQM pulls in that page via ajax and attaches it to the **current** page's DOM. When JQM pulls in a page via ajax it only pulls in that `data-role="page"` and does *not* load any of resources that may be in the `<head>` or elsewhere on the page.

From your question and markup it sounds like you are using asp.net, without seeing any more of your markup/code I'm pretty certain that your issue is that you don't have the necessary code for the linked page on your master page.

Normally to resolve this you can either place the unique content within the linked page's `data=role="page"` div, or when you call the page make sure the page is completely loaded, that is  without ajax. In your case since it looks like you are trying to call a server method the code to create the postback is probably outside of your second page's div in which case you will need to load the page without ajax, the easiest way you can do that is by adding the `data-ajax="false"` to your link.